# How can I resolve Promise pending output in nestjs framework?

Tags: http, promise, nestjs

I am building application in nodejs where I have to display the data by hitting the HTTPS endpoint. I am using Swagger UI to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the built in `HttpService` in NestJS, the service returns an [RxJS Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) which by default is not awaitable. You can tack on a `toPromise()` to convert the Observble to a promise that can be awaited and should have the awaited response from there. Otherwise, you can remove the `await` and make the function non-async, returning the observable and letting NestJS subscribe to it under the hood.

**Important side note**: You'll need to make sure that you don't try to send back the raw Axios response, as there are circular references that Nest will not e able to stringify. Look into the [observable pipe and map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) operators, or use a `then` after the `toPromise()` and map the response that way

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to user HttpService from NestJs, you can use [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) or [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise). These packages will return Promises by default and you can await them.

Hope it helps!